# Amazon ec2 download file

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using an ec2 instance to convert some videos online. Is it possible to make that converted file available for public download? Like I could send a link to my client where they could download the videos?

Otherwise I would have to download the file myself, reupload to mega.co.nz or something and send the link to the client.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, upload it to s3. You could also do the conversion with amazon elastic transcoder instead of keeping an instance up all the time.

Comment: tnks, how do i upload it to s3 from the instance desktop? btw, having the instance open all the time will make the system slower and slower ? Or can I expect the same performance? thank you

Comment: Desktop? Windows? Video conversion can be scripted and automated. All you need is an s3 client. There are a number of options depending on the platform you are on.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the file available, you can install a [web server](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache) or [FTP server](https://wiki.debian.org/vsftpd). Since I don't know which operating system you are using, I'm including guides on how to install one of those servers in Debian Linux - this will probably also work for you if you're using Ubuntu.